# NTFS/GPT Mount exited with Exit Code 13

Tags: external, ntfs, mount, ubuntu-11.10, hard-drive

This is a duplicated post since I didn't get any help on askubuntu.com.

I have a 1TB external hard drive that I recently formatted to NTFS. It was mounting on my Ubuntu 11.10 fine until just now. I didn't make any changes to affect my OS or my exhdd.

The error that I get is:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

I did read [**this**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19069/error-mounting-mount-exited-with-exit-code-13) and [**this**](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/). But neither helped.

I tried installing `ntfsfix` but no such package exists anymore.
I have never used this HDD on a windows machine. If I need to use an other machine to do stuff to fix this, I have access to a mac.

Any advice?

This is my sudo fdisk -l output:
What in the world is GPT? I didn't do that. It used to be NTFS.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000586fb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2148   961320312   480659082+  83  Linux
/dev/sda2       961320313   976773167     7726427+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5       961320314   976773167     7726427   83  Linux

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xcfd88605

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is the thing that worked:

1. I first needed to get `ntfs-3g` (`sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`)
2. Run `sudo fdisk -l` to figure out where the mount point is. Mine was `/dev/sdb1`
3. I ran `ntfsfix -b /dev/sdb1` and that fixed the problem.

Comment: ntfsfix worked for me. The output said: "
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
The alternate bootsector is usable
Rewriting the bootsector
The boot sector has been rewritten"

Comment: I tried to follow these steps and It says invalid option b while i was trying to do specified procedure. Help me out for this issue.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I did not use the -b flag. This flag will clear the list of bad sectors. If you suspect disk errors you should probably not use this flag.

Answer (score 0):

> **Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0)**. Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Input/output error
> NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run *chkdsk /f* on Windows then reboot into Windows **twice**. The usage of the */f* parameter is very important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1).
> Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.

**Solution :-**

1. sudo fdisk -l
2. sudo ntfsfix /dev/select_disk_name
3. To find Disk name:
   Go dashboard -> Disk utility -> Click disk  -> then show Device /Dev/***